# Was Looney Tunes considered a cartoon for adults?

Tags: cinema-history, looney-tunes

My siblings and I watched Looney Tunes growing up. This was before I was aware there was such a thing as cartoons for adults. Adults wouldn't really watch Looney Tunes, except when they were with us.

This was in the 1990s, but Looney Tunes started in the 1930s. Moreover, it is quite violent. I would think twice before showing it to a child today. Besides the beating with blunt weapons and dynamite explosions, there are multiple veiled references to rape, and at least one instance where Yosemite Sam proposes to "draw and quarter" Bugs Bunny. Check out that term on Wikipedia.

My question is: In the heyday of Looney Tunes, in the 1940s and 1950s, was it considered an adult or a kids cartoon?

Comment: Note the difference between "cartoon for adults" and "adult cartoon". The latter can be interpreted to contain sexual content or be of a pornographic nature.

Comment: _"Check out that term on Wikipedia."_ I'm not getting into a "where is the line" argument about appropriate behavior, but the fact that you'd need to look up what it means before understanding its (allegedly) offensive nature inherently proves that the mention by itself is not inappropriate for children. There are _plenty_ of jokes targeted at adults in kids' movies and shows, specifically in a way that it sounds harmless _unless_ you already understand the hidden reference being made.

Comment: I'd venture to say that the world was saner back then. :-) We also grew up on tales like Grimm and seven headed dragons slayed by the youngest son of the king and we neither turned into homicidal maniacs nor were harmed in any other way. Your kids should also have the chance to grow up without us stupid adults trying to remove everything from their sight because of some passing societal fads. Let them watch it freely and be there to help them learn what is what in life instead of trying to shield them from any exposure, gradually learning the difference between tales and reality,

Comment: @Flater: Good point about "adult cartoon" having racier meanings.  But given the context of this question title, that alternate meaning didn't even occur to me.  So English learners don't have to worry *too* much or be embarrassed every time an English phrase could be interpreted sexually. (Many common words have been used as euphemisms.)

Comment: "it is quite violent" reminds me of a comment I read on Youtube. There was this animated series for children from the DC Animated Universe that I watched, which I liked a lot. The guy commented how his younger brother was scared by it, although I wasn't when I was younger.

Comment: Doesn't cartoon violence have a very different effect from violence shown at all realistically, with people (of all ages) treating them very differently?  Look for example at [Punch-and-Judy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punch_and_Judy) puppet shows, which despite strong slapstick violence (assault, murder, sometimes hanging) are usually aimed at children, often quite young children.

Comment: Looney Tunes were **family entertainment**, back when "family entertainment" literally meant "interesting to the whole family", not "only for kids".

Comment: Such "violence" was common even in Disney cartoons of that time.

Comment: @Flater - "draw and quarter" is not "offensive", it's an extreme form of violence and torture that is nightmare fuel even for adults. That's the point being made here.

Comment: @Davor Cartoon violence does not equate to the goriness of its real world counterpart, that's a pretty standard trope. Falling from a greath height is also a terrible way to die (think of the splat in real life!), but Wile E Coyote is _seen_ falling from great height. Gun violence is terrible but Elmer Fudd is a hunter and therefore is _seen_ carrying and shooting a gun (as is Yosemite Sam). Those are actual on-screen events, whereas the "draw and quarter" is merely a _reference_ without further explanation, and requiring external knowledge. That's a long way from being inappropriate by itself

Comment: @Davor In other words: if blunt force trauma only gives you a bump on the head, cutting damage shaves your fur or cuts your clothes, gunfire soots up your face, falling from a greath height makes you fall in a crater and/or flattens you, ... then drawing and quartering would similarly only elongate your body. If you try to judge any cartoon by every possible real world consequence to anything that might happen _or even just get referenced_ in that cartoon, then the medium of kids television would largely cease to exist, as would the freedom to explore non-realistic environments.

Comment: @RonJohn In fact, the whole concept of "children's entertainment", i.e. content that's aimed solely at children and not even attempting to be at all entertaining to adults, is relatively new.  You started to see that in the 1970's, and it really took off in the 80's (much of modern children's programming is all-but-unwatchable for anyone above the age of 10), but before that, most content aimed at children was also designed to be entertaining for their parents as well.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I think that happened as "they" started making movies with more explicit violence, foul language and sexual content after the collapse of the Hays Code.  This is exemplified by the need to add "fuck" to movies to ensure they'll get an "R" rating so that people will think they're "for adults".  Compare that to movies like "North By Northwest" or "Imitation Of Life".

Comment: @RonJohn It might also have to do with the 70s being a period where multi-TV-set households started to become a thing. When there was only one TV set in the household, everyone watched what Dad wanted to watch, so it needed to be appropriate for all.

Comment: @shoover there were only four networks (including PBS) and some Independent channels, so the options weren't that great.  We watched what everyone agreed to watch, or went and did something else (read a book, work on crafts, play the organ with headphone, etc).  Nothing on TV was anything that my grandparents would get upset about, even if they didn't enjoy it.

Comment: @Gábor, I'd venture to say that the violence of cartoons and other sources are the reason why violence is still acceptable and practiced so openly today. If kids see that the only thing that happens when you shoot someone in the face is that their beak/nose rotates around their face, then they aren't likely to try it out for themselves. Remember the backyard WWE style wrestling in the 90's that caused so many injuries? People still think you can body slam someone from +8' in the air and walk away from it with no problems, and some of those people are adult. Kids will follow the example.

Answer (score 26):

> In the heyday of Looney Tunes, in the 1940s and 1950s, was it considered an adult cartoon or a kids cartoon?

### Both

Cartoons were shown to all audiences as "filler" between movies, much as trailers and previews are today.

Certainly the cartoons are "violent" but it is **cartoon** violence and is not subject to the limitations and censorship rules then and, more recently, now.

I'm not sure why you think adults would not watch Looney Tunes, comic strips in the newspapers were very popular in the period in question, and these are merely animated versions of the same.

Modern adults *might* not watch these movies any more but certainly, in the day, these were highly popular with all audiences.

Comment: "it is cartoon violence and is not subject to the limitations and censorship rules then and, more recently, now" - You mean it was not subject to the same limitations as movies and TV shows? I'm under the impression there have been more restrictions in the past 25 years (like no blood and no realistic gun) than the shows I watched in the 90s.

Comment: @Clockwork Don't cartoons fulfill these limitations automatically? Even if a cartoon does contain blood and/or guns, they're not going to look realistic.

Comment: @Llewellyn Yeah, but when I read stuffs about "Batman: The Animated Series", it seems like they have been over stretching the boundaries of what was allowed, a lot of time. There was this episode where they literally killed off several of the main characters. But to avoid censorship, they passed it as a dream episode.

Comment: @Llewellyn There also was an episode where you had a close in of the Joker smiling with blood dripping off his mouth, with a knife in his hand. I think I read somewhere that it nearly got them in trouble too.

Comment: How about "comedic violence?" or "slapstick?" There's not much space between how characters in Loony Tunes treated one another vs. how The Three Stooges treated each other.

Comment: @Llewellyn: Go watch some anime and then tell us the violence looks unrealistic.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I'm thinking you got something there about "comedic violence", as it's depicted in a non-lethal way, and the characters seem to always recover from anything that could have been lethal (e.g. blowing dynamite). Meanwhile, the animated series I was talking about are more focused on realism.

Comment: When I said "cartoon", I meant the typical toon style. I know there are other styles of animated movies, but they're not the focus of this question.

Comment: For an interesting side topic on this, Dee Snider testified about censorship and cartoon-styled violence in front of Congress in relation to Twisted Sister's slapstick comedy in their music videos.

Comment: Another example: The Simpsons is able to get away with what seems like child abuse because Bart is a cartoon.

Answer (score 9):

> Was Looney Tunes considered a cartoon for adults?

**Yes**, it was more of later developments which made it kid-friendly. From [Chicago Tribune](https://www.chicagotribune.com/news/ct-xpm-2002-11-03-0211030434-story.html#:%7E:text=%27%20Looney%20Tunes.&text=%22The%20Warner%20cartoons%20were%20aimed,houses%20before%20the%20feature%20presentation.):

> Age segregation also is a fairly new development in animation as well, according to animation lecturer Robert McKimson Jr., whose father directed 35 Bugs Bunny cartoons and created Foghorn Leghorn, Tasmanian Devil and Speedy Gonzales, among other characters, for Warner Bros.' Looney Tunes.

> > "The Warner cartoons were aimed strictly for adults--they were never meant for children," McKimson said.

> Warner cartoons and other animated short subjects (Disney characters, Popeye, Tom and Jerry and so on) were screened for audiences of all ages at movie houses before the feature presentation. But when television began packing Saturday mornings and after-school hours with those classics during the `60s, many were trimmed of excessive violence, sexual innuendo and drug and alcohol references.

> Or, as McKimson puts it: "They chopped the hell out of them."

Comment: They still had Bugs Bunny cross-dressing to seduce Elmer Fudd when I watched them on TV in the 60's and 70's. Was there more extreme sexual innuendo than this?

Comment: @Barmar I think the depiction of "seduce" was sufficiently vague to allow a child-friendly interpretation.